Nginx matching incorrect block - Ipv4 and IPv6
I moved my AWS instance to a public IPv6 address only to avoid the public IPv4 charges introduced a little while back. I have about six domains hosted on an EC2 server running Nginx, with CloudFlare as DNS and CDN. CloudFlare connects to my origin server over IPv6 only, and makes the domains available over IPv4 and IPv6.
The websites are working properly over https, but I was finding odd behavior with http requests. When I made an http request to one domain it returned the website for another one of my domains. It took me quite a while to work out why.
For example - I curl example.com and I get back a redirect to example2.com
curl -v http://example.com
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx
< Content-Type: text/html
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://example2.com

Here's the Nginx config - consider it pseudocode it may not pass "nginx -t".
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;  
}

server {
  server_name example.com;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;

  root     /var/www/example/;
}

server {
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name example2.com;
  return 301 https://example2.com$request_uri;  
}

server {
  server_name example2.com;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;

  root     /var/www/example2/;
}


When I reviewed Digital Oceans Nginx Location Matching guide I finally worked out the problem. Nginx matches by listen port and protocol first, only if there's more than one block on that listening port then it matches the server_name.
When I had moved to IPv6 I had updated all of the https servers to listen on both IPv4 and IPv6, but I'd missed updating most of the http redirect domains to listen on IPv6. Once I had the redirect servers listen on IPv6 as well as IPv4 things started working as expected.
The key steps in solving the problem were:

Using another Linux server, with the hosts file modified to point directly at the origin server rather than CloudFlare (not sure if that mattered much)
"curl -v http://example.com"
Reading the digital ocean guide - though it doesn't mention IPv6 it helped a lot

Here's the working pseudocode configuration
server {
  # THE LINE BELOW WAS THE PROBLEM
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;  
}

server {
  server_name example.com;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;

  root     /var/www/example/;
}

server {
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name example2.com;
  return 301 https://example2.com$request_uri;  
}

server {
  server_name example2.com;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;

  root     /var/www/example2/;
}

